# Threads and Critical Section correct approach

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Right now have a multi-thread scheme like this:

```
//global variables   
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  ControlFile: TextFile;
  MaxThreads, iThreads: integer;
  MyCritical: TCriticalSection;
```

The ControlFile is accessed by the threads, that do a ReadLn, and perform actions with the line obtained:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HostLine: AnsiString;
  FileHandle: integer;
begin
  MyCritical:= TCriticalSection.Create;
  MaxThreads:= 100;
  iThreads:= 0;
  while not(eof(ControlFile)) and (iThreads < MaxThreads) do
    begin
      inc(iThreads);
      ReadLn(ControlFile, HostLine);
      MyThread.Create(HostLine);
    end;
end;
```

this block is the first doubt. I'm creating 100 threads, each one created received the current line of the textfile. But the problem is that on threads.onterminate, I execute this:

```
procedure MyThread.MainControl(Sender: TObject);
var
  HostLine: string;
begin
  try
    MyCritical.Acquire;
    dec(iThreads);
    while not(eof(ControlFile)) and (iThreads < MaxThreads) do
      begin
        inc(iThreads);
        ReadLn(ControlFile, HostLine);
        MyThread.Create(HostLine);
      end;
  finally
    MyCritical.Release;
  end;

end;
```

The idea is to keep creating new threads, until the textfile finishes. But if one thread terminate, and execute this procedure, before the first while finished, what happens? The main thread, from button2click will be accessing the file, and the thread's procedure too. This looks strange to me. And the Critical Section, should be global or thread local? And this procedure, MainControl, that opens new threads until the end of the file, should be global or thread local?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? If you have CPU intensive threads you should only create threads equal to the number of CPU cores in your system, any excess thread will only decrease performance due to the switching overhead.

Comment: Yes... In fact I hate threads, and for me I wouldn't use them. But I need this because the boss is asking... We will send the line of the txt file via http request inside the thread...

Comment: I love threads, they allow for a responsive UI and in some cases better performance / speed. However I hate working with threads. I also hate paying my bills, but it has to be done :-)

Comment: Yes exactly... That's why I don't want to discuss the final achieve here, because I'm into something that even if I don't agree, I need to do, maybe after done I can prove that something better can be done without threads... But for now I need to do this, and in the right way.

Comment: *But for now I need to do this.* You need to do what exactly? We cannot know what you are trying to do. You've shown a bare minimum of information and code. We can't see what's in the threads. There are already a number of mistakes. I'm voting to close this because it's a long way from answerable.

Comment: Anyway, as whosrdaddy says, 100 threads is waaaaaaaay worse than just one thread. Creating 100 threads on a quad core processor is like putting a 100 cylinder engine inside a car. Sure, it adds more power, but the weight and fuel to power it will actually make the thing less efficient.

Comment: @JerryDodge That's simply not universally true.  We don't know enough about what OP is doing to say whether or not 100 threads is too many.  The OS will routinely have this many threads running or more.  A web browser likewise.  Other examples are not hard to find.

Comment: @J... Partially true, the things which run 100+ threads at once, those threads are doing different things. What I'm referring to (and assuming OP is talking about) is using 100 threads to do the same thing.

Comment: I understand that the thread.execute is important, but unfortunately I can't post this, because I don't have it yet... But in theory it will send the line received on the Create via Indy HTTP, after this receive the answer from the server, and if the answer is 'correct', put some info on main form.

Comment: @JerryDodge Sometimes the same thing is different.  Maybe the text file contains a large list of IP addresses and information to send to them... 100 simultaneous TCP connections isn't crazy.  The point is that we don't know. `HostsFile` seems to suggest...

Comment: @J... yes, it's something like TCP connections, because we will be using indy to send the line to the backend server, and receive the answer...

Comment: Have one thread parsing the file. Start up worker threads to your max worker thread limit, adding up a protected counter. When each worker thread is done, they count down the counter. This means that the parser thread can apply more worker threads if needed. Having said all this, a thread pool taking worker information from a thread-safe queue is a much simpler approach.

Comment: @J... hunders of TCP connections. No problem. Just use the I/O completion ports over the built-in system thread pool. Pity that so many people overlooks the built-in thread pool...

Comment: In any case, when it comes to spawning multiple threads which are to perform the same task "simultaneously", I still don't see a need to go more than twice the number of cores. Sure network activity is an ideal situation to use more threads. However there's still always the bottleneck of bandwidth and CPU.

Comment: @TLama Agreed, IOCP can be a great solution to a lot of problems, but there are some for which it is not.  If each work package has any sort of transaction with complexity it may not be the best solution.  Again, we don't (or rather didn't) know what OP is doing so it is very difficult to suggest what approach may be best.  I maintain that a large number of threads is not *always* the wrong solution to every problem - whether that is the case for OP we can only speculate.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I am not sure it's such a stellar idea to have different threads read from the same text file. It's not that it can't work, but I think it would be much cleaner to simply read the whole thing into a TStringList variable up front, which can then be shared among threads, if needed.

If you do go with what you already have, your critical section must be acquired in the main loop also - the threads that you spawn will start executing immediately by default, so it looks like there could be a race between your main thread and the threads that run MainControl, though you don't show exactly how that call is going to be made.

The critical section needs to be a global variable, as you have it, or a field/property of a global class in order to be shared among threads.

My final point is that it's probably not the greatest idea to create 100 threads either. Unless your threads are mostly waiting on I/O or events, you should generally not have more threads than you have CPU cores. It's better to use a pool of worker threads and a queue of work items that can then be doled out to the running threads. There's supposedly built-in support for some of this in more recent Delphi RTLs. I personally use my own tried and true custom thread pool implementation, so I can't give you any specific help with that part.

Comment: thank you for the answer... the MainControl is specified on the thread constructor, to be executed onterminate: `OnTerminate:= MainControl;`

Comment: - and is `HostsFile` and `ControlFile` really one and the same?

Comment: Yes is the same, I'm sorry, I'll edit the main code for the same name.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `OnTerminate` is already synchronised.

```
procedure TThread.DoTerminate;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnTerminate) then Synchronize(CallOnTerminate);
end;
```

So the critical section is not actually needed at all because all the code you've shown runs in the context of the main thread.

Comment: This answer aside, there are many more approaches you may wish to consider instead: 1) Instead of re-creating a separate thread for each line, start with a fixed no of threads; let each thread loop through its share of the strings. 2) As variation on 1, have each thread pull next line off a queue as soon as it finishes processing the previous string. 3) Assuming other threads may be waiting on other I/O, consider using IOCP. 4) Use a single thread to create each child thread, and use a semaphore to limit the number of child threads in existence at any point in time.